# Does there exist any function of two independent variables whose both the repeated limits exist and are unequal and also the double limit exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Does there exist any function of two independent variables whose both the repeated limits do exist and are unequal and also the double limit exist?

I have tried to find out an example but I fail.Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x,b) \ne \lim_{y\rightarrow b}f(a,b)$ while $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)} f(x,y)$ exists?

Comment: I assume the OP means that $\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)$ and $\lim_{y\to b}\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)$ both exist but are not equal, and $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)$ also exists. The question has been asked very poorly, however.

Comment: When a question asks "does there exist ____," it's often a good idea to explore both possibilities. Spend some time trying to think of an example, but also spend some time trying to find a reason why there can't be one. You can switch back and forth between the tasks when you get tired of one of them. (Sometimes the effort in one direction will even give you an idea about the other possibility.)